# Euler Equations having double roots solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

If the Euler equation have the double roots as a solution, second  solution will be $y_2(x)=x^r\ln{x}$. What is its proof? or  how it can be derived? To find a second solution,we will use the fact that constant times the  solution is also a solution to linear homogeneous differential equations. Now why do we choose $\ln{x}$ as constant?why not any other constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can find answer to this question here$\rightarrow$[Euler equation having double roots or repeated roots as a solution[1DE](https://mathhelpboards.com/redirect-to/?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fmathhelpforum.com%2Fdifferential-equations%2F282014-euler-equation-having-double-roots-repeated-roots-solution.html)]